# Use of MaskedTextBox with text

Tags: c#, validation, text, maskedtextbox

I'm facing a simple problem that bugs me...

I have a MaskedTextBox and I want the user to be able to enter 3 numbers at the end :

"My Masked Text Box : XXX"

This text will be translated. The problem is, this control uses Microsoft's recipe to validate the input and in this example, the final display will look like this :

"My M_sked Text Box : *_*"

The letter 'a' is considered like a control caracter instead of a simple text caracter. I can backslash it but when the text is translated I have to do it again and I think it's ridiculous to have to do something like that...

I hope I'm being clear...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Are you using "A" or "a" as the mask character? If that's the case, why not use "0" or "9" depending on whether the digit is required or optional?

Comment: Mmm, let me explain this again... I want the entry to be 3 required numerics values. But I want to insert a text before the values, like : "My values : 000" but Microsoft uses my "a" as a mask caracter instead of a simple text caracter... Therefore, in my MaskedTextBox, I get "My v_lues : ___". I hope my second explanation is better !

Comment: Why not adding the text as Label before the textbox?

Comment: Yes, that makes the query clearer. Could you possibly know the total length of text characters that you want? If you do know, then you could use a mix of "L" and "0".

Comment: I want to avoid adding a label, that's why I chose this solution... I want only 3 number digits at the end of the mask. "My values : 000" and I want "My Values : " to be just a simple text, I could write "My v\alues : 000" to avoid the "a" being considered as a control caracter, but when the text will be translated I'll have to make extra-work for nothing...

Comment: You're going to have to do extra work when you translate regardless, as long as you have the label text embedded in the textbox itself. The masked textbox is really not designed to handle a string of static text. Why do you want to avoid adding a label?

Comment: Yeah I felt like it wasn't designed to support static text... It's annoying... I don't want a label because I found it was more convenient to have only one control !

Comment: There's always the option of inheriting from TextBox and rolling your own custom validation routines, but that sounds like way too much work to me. :-) Alternatively, you could consider using a TextBox with a cue banner to replace the label (see here for sample code: http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-1-cue-banners-in-windows-forms-em_setcuebanner-text-prompt/), but you'd still have to implement your own validation because I doubt that EM_SETCUEBANNER will work properly with a MaskedTextBox, even though it ultimately inherits from the TextBoxBase.

Answer (score 0):

The 'a' needs to be quoted as a literal.  The Mask should be something like:

`My M\asked Text Box : 000`

You should use '9' rather than '0' as the placeholder for an optional numerical character.

Of course any other of the characters that match mask options should be 'literal' too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

---

After reading the comments I'd like to add another suggestion (you clearly understood about literals -- the problem is your translation.)

Would it be feasible to run the translated text strings through a filter that put literal-quotes in where possible? It's not that nice a solution, because if Microsoft added new control characters it'll break your filter, but I think it would work.